# Joining more than two WHERE statements in Query Language

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language, and-operator

So I am trying to use a simple QUERY function in Google Sheets where I want to select based on TWO parameters. Simple logic, and documentation says use the AND operator. The problem is I am searching for text via Cell Reference.

So here is my function

```
=QUERY(A1:D6,"select A where C='" &K1&'"" & "and D='" &K2"'")
```

Unfortunately it throws up an ERROR. I understand that Cell References that are text based need to be in single quotes (which themselves need to be in double quotes), but I am unable to join two WHERE statements.

What is the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close indeed, please try:

```
=query(A1:D6,"select A where C='"&K1&"' and D='"&K2&"' ")
```

Comment: Haha thanks! I think we figured it at the same time ;)

Answer (score -1):

Welp! I was missing an concatenation symbol (&) at the end of the final cell reference K2.

```
=QUERY(A1:D6,"select A where C='" &K1&'"" & "and D='" &K2&"'")
```